# Python lightweight server for embedded devices

Tags: python, embedded

Is there any lightweight Python server for embedded processors ( to 10 MB )? Do I need any framework for developing pages on this small server or can I do that in plain Python?

Comment: dup ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302615/embedded-web-server-in-python

Comment: Could you specify which embedded processor you're using?  Python would have to run on that processor, for starters.

Answer (score 3):

[bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) might be what you're looking for.  It is a light-weight framework, as well as a server.

[web.py](http://webpy.org/) is similar.

I'm not sure of your exact needs or requirements, but they are two good options to investigate.